# Which direction should the back arrow point to in an arabic web-site?

Tags: html, web, arabic

I am working on a web-site which is compatible with Arabic language as well. But for security reasons, the browser back button will kill the session and user is expected to use the back button present on the page only.

In case of Arabic language, in which direction should the back arrow point to? 
Is there any standard for the Right to Left layout pages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a good fit for http://ux.stackexchange.com, not so much SO.

Comment: Sidenote: killing the session "for security reasons" on using the browser's back button? Please don't do that, there's no real sane reason why you'd need to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow should not only change directions, but possibly positions (i.e. from the top left to the top right).

http://www.google.com/design/spec/usability/bidirectionality.html

Comment: Updated url: https://m2.material.io/design/usability/bidirectionality.html